# RQT_RVIZ RVIZ Remote ROS_IP

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-hydro, ros-hostname, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

Hydro-RQT/RViz did not use ROS_IP, ROS_MASTER_URI or ROS_HOSTNAME...
"rostopic list" works fine.

Bug or feature ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80226/rqt_rviz-rviz-remote-ros_ip/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-17**:
Please clarify what your problem is in a way that it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved

Workaround script:

## my own ip address from RVIZ Workstation

export ROS_HOSTNAME=`/bin/hostname -I`

## remote headless system MockBot

export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://$1:11311"

echo Using ROS MASTER at $ROS_MASTER_URI from $ROS_HOSTNAME

ping -c 1 $1
rostopic list
rosrun rqt_rviz rqt_rviz

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0